# Quantiles as columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (dummy df)

```
id    category    price
1       a           50
2       a           30
3       a           10
6       a           5
0       b           20
7       c           80
```

I want to group by category and quantile price into different bins [0.25,0.5,0.75]

I did

```
quantile = df[['category', 'price']].groupby('category').quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])
```

But its giving me result in the the below format:

```
category    price
a        0.25  xx    (xx,yy,zz are just temporary used value, not real)
         0.5   yy
         0.75  zz
```

I wanted my result in this format:

```
category    0.25    0.5    0.75
  a          xx      yy      zz  (temporary used values)
  b          qq      ee      ef
```

where I can get to know the categories belong into what price bins.

Is there any way to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
quantile = df[['category', 'price']].groupby('category').quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])['price']
                                    .unstack()
print (quantile)
           0.25  0.50  0.75
category                   
a          8.75  20.0  35.0
b         20.00  20.0  20.0
c         80.00  80.0  80.0
```

Or:

```
quantile = df.groupby('category')['price'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75]).unstack()
print (quantile)
           0.25  0.50  0.75
category                   
a          8.75  20.0  35.0
b         20.00  20.0  20.0
c         80.00  80.0  80.0
```